# Track size of a directory over time

Tags: logs, directory, size

I have a directory and I want to log, from now on, its size every day. That is, at some time of day, every day, I want to compute the size of this directory, and append it in some file along with the date.

**NOTE:** By size of the directory I mean the size of the all the contents, recursively.

What's the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 10):

You could run something [`du`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) from a cron job. With GNU tools, `du -sb dir/` would give you the size in bytes of the directory and all files within it, recursively (plus the directory name, but we can remove that). And you can get the date with `date`. E.g.

```
$ printf "$(date +"%F %T") $(du -sb /tmp)\n" 
2018-07-03 15:25:57 24246930    /tmp
```

Then put that in a cron job and direct the output to a file. A [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry to run at 06:00 every day could be something like this (of course, I'm only using `/tmp` here as just an example):

```
0 6 * * * printf "$(date +"\%F \%T") $(du -sb /tmp)\n" >> /tmp/tmp-size.log
```

The percent signs need to be escaped for `cron`.

You could use `du -sk` for kilobytes, or `du -sh` for "human-readable" auto-scaling output. The options accepted by `du` may be different on another system.

Use something like `du ... | sed -e 's/[[:blank:]].*//'` instead, if you want to remove the pathname that `du` prints.

Comment: Good solution. 
You might want to add this in the crontab of root user to avoid potential permission issues `du: cannot read directory /tmp/systemd-private-...: Permission denied`